# Divs are getting pushed? 3 column layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am building my website on Bootstrap 2.0. Im trying to make a 3 column layout like on this picture:
http://prntscr.com/1jsb2w 
 The problem is that the divs keep getting pushed (Im a novice in CSS :)

Right now my page looks like this:
http://prntscr.com/1jscbp

My html & css (Note I have done some additional stylings to the html file, Im not including bootstrap.css because I have not done any changes to it. Im not using external stylesheets (except the bootstrap ones)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Foxfile</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin:50px;
        background-image:url(img/noisy_grey.png);
      }
      #wrapper {
       background-image:url(img/noisy_white.png);
       border-radius:7px;
      }
      #projectList {
        width:100%;
      }
      #projectList p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,font,a {
        padding:10px;
      }
      #projectList img {
        margin:10px;
      }
      .circle_preview {
        border-radius:150px;
        background-image:url(img/noisy_grey.png);
        height:30px;
        width:30px;
        padding:10px;
      }
      footer {
        color:#fff;
        margin:10px;
        font-weight:bold;
      }
      .position-center {
        text-align:center;
        position:relative;
      }
    </style>

    <div id='wrapper'>

    <div id='projectList'>
        <div id='projectListTop'>
         <h3> Recent Software </h3>
        </div>
        <a href='#'> <img class='circle_preview' src='img/avast_icon.png'> Avast Security </a> <br />
        <a href='#'> <img class='circle_preview' src='img/itunes_logo.png'> iTunes </a> <br />
        <a href='#'> <img class='circle_preview' src='img/utorrent_logo.jpg'> Avast Security </a> <br />
    </div>
    <div id='projectList' class='position-center'>
        <div id='projectListTop'>
         <h3> Popular Software </h3>
        </div>
        <a href='#'> <img class='circle_preview' src='img/avast_icon.png'> Avast Security </a> <br />
        <a href='#'> <img class='circle_preview' src='img/itunes_logo.png'> iTunes </a> <br />
        <a href='#'> <img class='circle_preview' src='img/utorrent_logo.jpg'> Avast Security </a> <br />
    </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can say right off the bat that you need to improve your markup. Never use the same `id` twice, that's what `class` is for.

Comment: But could that be the problem?

Comment: It's not THE problem, but it could very well be a part of it.

Comment: I guess I can just use tables to lay out the page, instead of divs

Comment: `NO! DON'T USE TABLES!`  You're missing an opening body tag.

Comment: You could, but a lot of people would advise against it. Personally, if you can get the results you want, go for it. That being said, it's usually better to learn how to do it the right (or best) way to begin with rather than developing bad habits...

Comment: I don't see any `Bootstrap` in your markup.

Comment: I removed it and left only the part of the code that I have added (to make it easier to read)

Comment: I think you need to make a jsFiddle similar to this one (http://jsfiddle.net/TpvDx/) and include more code if you want help.

Comment: You should use `display:inline-block` for the three column divs set to 33.33333% width and have a wrapper div set to `width:100%;`. Or alternatively have the wrapper div set to `display:table;` and have the three child divs set to `display:table-cell;`

Comment: Why are you not using the grid system from Twitter Bootstrap?  Your columns should be set up like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gZbeT/1/.  Note: you might have to make the viewport a little wider to see the columns.

Comment: @adaam you should turn your comment into an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've compiled a series of different methods to achieve a 3 column layout as requested by the OP.

http://jsfiddle.net/adaam2/amxUz/4/

**Method 1 (Inline Block)**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inline-block">inline-block</div>
    <div class="inline-block">inline-block</div>
    <div class="inline-block">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
.inline-block {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:32%;
}
```

- Note that there is a whitespace issue when setting elements aligned horizontally to inline block.

**Method 2 (Table + Table Cell):**

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="table-cell">table cell</div>
    <div class="table-cell">table cell</div>
    <div class="table-cell">table cell</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table-wrapper {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:33%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:red;
}
```

**Method 3 (Float)**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="float">inline-block</div>
    <div class="float">inline-block</div>
    <div class="float">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.float {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:pink;
}
```

*** This method is good as you don't encounter the whitespace issue as you do with setting the child elements to inline-block.

If you look at my JsFiddle, I've added some extra styling, including `box-sizing:border-box;` which allows you to add padding and borders amongst other things without affecting the grid layout.